# How can I check if request is post in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I remember using something like

```
$this->getRequest()->isPost()
```

but it seems like there isn't such a function. How can I check if the request is post so I can validate the form etc

Comment: In which context? Your code snippet above should work fine in a controller

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`$this->getRequest()` in the context of a controller is annoted to return an object of class `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`. `isPost()` is a method of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` which is derived from `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`.
So your IDE cannot offer this method, but it is there.

Comment: Great answer. One thing you can do is add an inline var type comment, eg `/* @var $request Zend_Controller_Request_Http */` then fetch the controller request object into a `$request` variable, eg `$request = $this->getRequest()`. If using Netbeans or a PDT based IDE, you should get the code completion for the HTTP class.

Answer (score 17):

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
{
    echo "this is post request";
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "this is not the post request";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
   if($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
       echo "You've got post!";
   }
```

isPost() should be there too, though, I don't know why you don't find it.

Comment: that's what ZF does internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->_request->isPost){
echo "Values is POST"; 
}
else
{
 echo "Try again";
}
```

I just learnt it. Yepppiiiiiiiiii !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `_request` is a protected attribute it'd be preferable to use the getter.

Answer (score 0):

if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
echo "this is post request";

Answer (score 0):

Not all ZendFramework applications instantiate a Request instance into the Controller. For SocialEngine, the following works:

```
<?php
    if (Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        ...
    }
```